# rails render_to_string giving errors with partial view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, partial-views

I am getting `ActionView::MissingTemplate` error when using render_to_string method with partial views, below the code

```
 bizz = render_to_string(:partial => "biz_new",:layout => false)
```

Even though i have explicitly specified `:layout => false`, i am getting the MissingTemplate error always.

But render_to_string with normal views works fine in the same project. what could be the reason?

below the stack trace

> ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing partial businesses/biz_new with
>   {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:text,
>   "*/*"], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths
>   "/home/ramesh/works/xxx/app/views",
>   "/home/ramesh/works/xxx/vendor/plugins/asset_packager/app/views"):

Comment: @fl00r, under businesses directory,  i left businesses because the above code runs in businesses controller.

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
 render_to_string("_biz_new", :formats => [:html], :layout => false, :locals => {:biz => @biz})
```

render_to_string needs the starting underscore and the .html extension.

Comment: is there any way to get host or set host somehow?

Answer (score 3):

As Mike Kijewski mentioned, you can include the underscore at the beginning of the partial name, but if you use the .html in the end you will get a deprecation warning. A more straightforward way is this:

```
render_to_string(:partial => "folder_name/_partial_name", :formats => [:html], :layout => false, :locals => {:a_needed_argument_for_the_partial => @arg})
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like rails is expecting the file to be in format txt. What's the file named ? Try naming it:

```
_biz_new.txt.erb
```

-or-

```
businesses/_biz_new.txt.erb
```

Comment: the file named  _biz_new.html.erb. whats the reason for using txt.erb?

Comment: it looks like rails is looking for files of format txt. Just a hunch, give it a shot.

Comment: I have one last idea. Try renaming the partial to _biz.erb and call to render that partial. Otherwise I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where I was using `formats: "html"` but needed to be changed to a symbol like `formats: :html`.

Answer (score -1):

Had similar issue.

I found a solution:

`render_to_string(model, :formats => [:html])`