# Rails 7 - render_to_string - MissingTemplate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm facing an issue with my Rails app after upgrading it from Rails 6 to 7. When I try to `render_to_string` a template, I'm receiving ActionView::MissingTemplate exception.

As this was working fine, I can't help but to think there's some new approach to Rails 7, which I wasn't able to find.

My code below:

**Controller**

```rb
class SomethingController < ApplicationController

  ...
  def my_action
     html_string = render_to_string(template: 'something/template.html.erb', locals: {id: params[:id]})
  end
  
end
```

My expectation (and the behavior I used to have) was getting back the processed template view, but what I'm receiving back is the exception:

```rb
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template something/template.html.erb with {:locale=>[:"pt-BR", :pt], :formats=>[:pdf], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}.

Searched in:
  * "/Users/user/rails/rn_igreja/app/views"
  * "/Users/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/devise-i18n-1.10.2/app/views"
  * "/Users/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/devise-4.8.1/app/views"
  * "/Users/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actiontext-7.0.1/app/views"
  * "/Users/user/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionmailbox-7.0.1/app/views"
):

app/controllers/something_controller.rb:16:in `block in my_action'
app/controllers/something_controller.rb:12:in `my_action'
```

Additional details:

- Ruby version: 3.1.0
- Rails version: 7.0.2

I would really appreciate any clue to what I'm missing here.

Comment: This answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078439/rails-render-to-string-giving-errors-with-partial-view

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[@user973254](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72479400/rails-7-render-to-string-missingtemplate/72635551#comment128041176_72479400) helped me get this issue fixed, thanks to the comment:

> This answer might be helpful: [rails render_to_string giving errors with partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078439/rails-render-to-string-giving-errors-with-partial-view)

It turns out that it's now needed to pass also the `formats:` parameter with the `render_to_string` method.

My addition to the code, that got it working, was:

1. Adding the `formats:` parameter
2. Removing the `'html.erb'` portion of the `template:` parameter
3. Adding `layout: false` (which I haven't honestly tested to check if its that pivotal for this issue

Below I show the code that works.

```rb
class SomethingController < ApplicationController

  ...
  def my_action
      html_string = render_to_string(
        template: 'something/template',
        formats: [:html],
        locals: { id: params[:id] },
        layout: false
      )
  end
  
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an "uncommon" format (such as :kml or :kmz or :xls) remember to add it in `config/initializers/mime_type.rb` otherwise the render function may not recognize it.

I had the same problem after a Rails 7 upgrade and that was the solution

Comment: horyshiet that worked!